# "about the latter times"

Tags: phrase-choice

Situation: the student is asking about the possibility of having the next lesson with his teacher at 8:00 instead of usual 8:30. Teacher is answering:

> "This Friday, 8:00 is fine. Not sure, though, **about the latter times**"

Is it okay to say like that? Google on "latter times" seems to return a lot of religious context, but here the teacher is not implying anything religious. He only says that he is not sure if other subsequent lessons after this Friday are also possible to be held at 8:00

Comment: Teacher possibly meant 'later'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Can "later" really be used as an adjective?

Comment: Of course it can. Look in a dictionary. You are supposed to do that before asking on this site.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I DID look in the dictionary before asking - in Webster. Webster only presents "later" as an adverb: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/later  It looks rather unlikely to me that the editors simply forgot that it could also be an adjective.

Comment: 'Former' and 'latter' would refer to something/some things mentioned in a previous sentence. Please can you say what came before this. (I've moved this to the comments because I forgot which website I'm on!)

Comment: @brilliant - You ask, "Can't "latter" also refer to some future things that haven't been mentioned yet?" The answer is a definite No. 'Former' and 'latter' always refer to things that have already been mentioned. Except, as you say, in formulaic religious references.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - "Please can you say what came before this?" - I am sorry, but I can't because this whole example was created by me.

Comment: @brilliant - You ask, *"Can't "latter" also refer to some future things that haven't been mentioned yet?"* The answer is a definite No. 'Former' and 'latter' always refer to things that have already been mentioned. Except, as you say, in formulaic religious references.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I see. Thank you. Can you, please, tell me how you yourself express that thought that the teacher is trying to express in my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "This Friday, 8:00 is fine. Not sure, though, about the latter times"

Having understood the question better from the comments, I suggest the following

"This Friday, 8:00 is fine. Not sure, though, about the future times"

or simply

"This Friday, 8:00 is fine. Not sure, though, about in future."

Comment: "about the future times" doesn't really work there. All the times are 'future' times. Neither does 'in future'.

Comment: 'The later times' works fine, though.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the teacher meant to use 'later', and as an adjective:

> later
>
> adjective [ before noun ]
>
> (IN THE FUTURE)
>
> ​ B2 happening at a time in the future, or after the time you have
>   mentioned:
>
> We could catch a later train.
>   You can always change your password at a later date.

[Later (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/later)

This is repeated in Oxford:

[Later (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/later_2)

'Later' is shown as an adjective in the first 1828 edition of Webster's Dictionary

[Later (Webster 1828)](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/later)

By 1913 it was shown as both adjective and adverb:

[Later (Webster 1913)](https://www.websters1913.com/words/Later)

Although the current Merriam-Webster only says 'later' is an adverb, the current American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language gives both:

[Later (American Heritage)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=later)

Comment: Strange, how come Webster didn't mention that "later" could be an adjective? Is it, perhaps, because adjectival usage of "later" is chiefly British?

Comment: BTW, I just discovered that in your Cambridge Dictionary link there is "American" section. If you click on it, you'll see that "later" is mentioned there only as an adverb - just like in Webster. Not so in Oxford, though.

Comment: Having read your answer, I've lost my faith in Webster.

Comment: Using more than one dictionary from more than one English region is a good idea.

Comment: The comparative 'later' and plain 'late' are both capable of being adjective or adverb.